# angular-bootstrap toggle button how to use boolean instead of string or int

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui

I have a toggle button in test_page.js

HTML:

```
  <button type="button" class="my-button-toggle" ng-model="isTesting"
          btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="1" btn-checkbox-false="0">Enable Testing
  </button>
```

In my controller, I have

```
$scope.isTesting = parseInt($.cookie(constant.cookies.isTesting))

$scope.$watch('isTesting', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue)
        $.cookie(constant.cookies.isTesting, newValue)
    else
        $.removeCookie(constant.cookies.isTesting)
})
```

I use this function to turn on/off isTesting flag stored in jQuery cookie.

Now everything is working fine. But I want to use `true/false` instead of `1/0` in the html (for readability).

I have tried `btn-checkbox-true="true" btn-checkbox-false="false"`, the evaluated `newValue` in the `$watch` callback is a string `"true"/"false"`, not the boolean value.

In case you may ask, I do not use angular `$cookies` because some pages of my website is not using angular. (It should have nothing to do with the question. )

Comment: Its a problem of angular. In my code, i always use 1/0 for ng-checked and other directives.

Comment: I dont think it would make much sense changing the value to true or false. At the moment it says `btn-checkbox-true is equal to 1`. If you changed it to true, then it would read `btn-checkbox-true is equal to true` which to me is a bit strange. I assume it's there so you can use anything as the truthy operand and anything as the falsey operand. More complicated explaination of @Agop explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `btn-checkbox-true="1"` and `btn-checkbox-false="0"` to have `newValue` be `true` or `false`.

The defaults are `true`/`false`, but if you provide alternative values via `btn-checkbox-true/false`, they will be treated as strings.

Comment: I tried that and it is indeed boolean. But the weird thing is, after storing to cookie and retrieving it back, $scope.isTesting becomes string again

Comment: Cookies store strings, so when you read a cookie, you'll get a string. You'll need to manually parse your cookies.

Comment: This becomes as ugly as `parseInt($.cookie())`. Can jQuery cookie directly support the parsing?

Comment: should be `parseInt($.cookie(), 10)` dont forget the radix

Comment: it's also quite awkward to set the cookie by adding isTesting=true while unset the cookie by removing it. is it a better coding style (i.e. more popular convention) to remove `isTesting=true`, or to set `isTesting=false`?

Comment: This isn't really a matter of AngularJS anymore, but I'll leave my two cents. I recommend removing the cookie instead of setting it to a false value. This reduces the amount of cruft that your website leaves behind (alternatively, you may wish to use local storage instead of cookies). As for parsing the cookie, no, `js-cookie` won't do it for you. You can just use `if ($.cookie(...) === 'true')` rather than parsing it as an integer.